# Restore in-app purchase after a set of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have created a consumable in-app purchase which enables some images, texts, sound etc. These things should only be available for the user for 4 hours. After that time the same purchase should be available for purchase as normal. My question is how to cancel or restore (or what it's called) the products they buy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that consumable in app purchase can't be restored.  Once they are purchased they are "consumed".  If you want to let the user restore purchases for 4 hours after purchase you will need to manually do that yourself.  I do something similar to this using Parse (parse.com).  When a user makes a purchase it is easy to record that purchase on parse and then I can easily query parse for all purchases a user has made.

Comment: so do you mean I won't be able to do this with in-app purchases at all?